# What does it actually mean by Task Planning?

Tags: robotics

I have just started studying robotics. This is my first question to get started with robotics. Pardon me if this question is too naive.

What does it actually mean by [Task Planning](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/56654) in case of robotics?

How is it different from conventional "robot control"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Robot Motion control** is generally dealt with low-level navigation like localization (what is the current location of the robot), path planning (chose a path from a to b by avoiding obstacles).

**Tasking planning** is generally dealing with high-level planning. For example, task for a robot with a manipulator is to clean the desk (go to desk, find objects on desk and choose the order to pickup items, move the picked items to dusbin).